# How to write the Module Pattern in Typescript for an existing JavaScript Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, typescript, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

I am quite new to both Javascript and Typescript. I have to migrate the Javascript code into Typescript. Here is a Module pattern that returns itself instead of exposing private methods and property (Please correct me If I am wrong). So I don't know how to deal with this situation.

```
var MySocket = (function () {


    function MySocket(location, openCallback, closeCallback, errorCallback) {
        //Code Goes Here
    }



    MySocket.prototype.Open = function () {
        //Code Goes Here
    }

    MySocket.prototype.Close = function () {
        //Code Goes Here
    }



    return MySocket;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called the revealing module pattern. You can still use this in TypeScript. The 'modern' pattern would be to remove the IIFE and `return` statement and instead add an `export` modifier to `MySocket`:

```
export function MySocket(location, openCallback, closeCallback, errorCallback) {
   //Code Goes Here
}

MySocket.prototype.Open = function () {
  //Code Goes Here
}

MySocket.prototype.Close = function () {
  //Code Goes Here
}
```

However, the usage of this is slightly different. ES6 modules are expected to be imported from *other* ES6 modules using the `import` statement rather than just referring to the variable by name:

```
import { MySocket } from './MySocket'
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work and not sure how to maintain the encapsulation if I remove the IIFE and return. I add it to the namespace and export function export but didn't work. I tried it before.

Comment: With Es6 modules the encapsulation is the module itself. If you're still concatenating all of your files together then the Typescript export syntax isn't really appropriate for your use case. I would recommend you read up on how ES6 modules work to get a better understanding